# How to handle multiple checkboxes in a React Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a **React Component** that is looping through an array of data and is rendering a checkbox for each object in the array.

```js
"supplies": [{
    "deviceName": "OMEGAX d3241",
    "productName": "ZA1239",
    "productGroup": "hearing aid batteries",
    "productId": "1",
    "lastOrderDate": "2020-01-01",
    "nextAvailabilityDate": "2020-09-01",
    "quantity": 60
  },
  {
    "productGroup": "hearing aid accessories",
    "productId": "3",
    "availableForReorder": true,
    "lastOrderDate": "2019-06-30",
    "nextAvailabilityDate": "2019-12-15",
    "quantity": 10,
    "size": "6mm"
  },
  {
    "productName": "DOME",
    "productGroup": "hearing aid accessories",
    "productId": "4",
    "availableForReorder": true,
    "lastOrderDate": "2019-06-30",
    "nextAvailabilityDate": "2019-12-15",
    "quantity": 10,
    "size": "7mm"
  },
  {
    "productName": "WaxBuster Single Unit",
    "productGroup": "hearing aid accessories",
    "productId": "5",
    "availableForReorder": true,
    "lastOrderDate": "2019-06-30",
    "nextAvailabilityDate": "2019-12-15",
    "quantity": 10
  }
]
```

Most of this data is displayed in a **React Class Component**

```js
class SelectArrayItemsWidget extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedSupplies: new Map(),
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getReOrderBatteryAndAccessoriesInformationData();
  }

  handleChecked = e => {
    const supply = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      checkedSupplies: prevState.checkedSupplies.set(supply, isChecked),
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { supplies } = this.props;
    const { isChecked, checkedSupplies } = this.state;

    return supplies.map(supply => (
      <div key={supply.productId} className="order-background">
        <p className="ds-u-font-size--md ds-u-font-weight--bold">
          {supply.productName}
        </p>
        <div className="ds-u-border-left--10px ds-u-border-color--primary-alt">
          <div className="usa-alert-body mdot-alert-body">
            <p className="ds-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="ds-u-font-weight--bold">Battery: </span>
              {supply.productId}
            </p>
            <p className="ds-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="ds-u-font-weight--bold">Quantity: </span>
              {supply.quantity} <br />
              Approximately {supply.quantity} months supply
            </p>
            <p className="ds-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="ds-u-font-weight--bold">Last order date: </span>{' '}
              {moment(supply.lastOrderDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            !isChecked
              ? 'ds-u-background-color--white ds-u-color--link-default button-dimensions ds-u-border-color--primary ds-u-border--2px'
              : 'ds-u-background-color--primary button-dimensions ds-u-color--white ds-u-border-color--primary ds-u-border--2px'
          }
        >
          <input
            name={supply.productId}
            checked={!checkedSupplies.get(supply.productId)}
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={this.handleChecked}
          />
          <label htmlFor={supply.productId} className="main">
            Order batteries for this device
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}
```

I want the wrapping `div` for each checkbox to change text color and background color depending if that individual checkbox is checked. I am running an condition on the container:
`!isChecked
              ? 'vads-u-background-color--white vads-u-color--link-default button-dimensions vads-u-border-color--primary vads-u-border--2px'
              : 'vads-u-background-color--primary button-dimensions vads-u-color--white vads-u-border-color--primary vads-u-border--2px'`

But instead every time a check a checkbox none of the containers change their style properties.

Comment: I believe the main issue here is that `state.checkedSupplies` is instance of Map, and `Map.prototype.set` returns the same map all the time, i.e., reference to itself after mutation is performed. React runtime runs comparison of previous and current state, sees that the two are equal, and therefore doesn't update the DOM. To fix, consider using a plain object instead of Map, or maybe still use a Map but make the update of it an immutable operation.

Comment: There's also immutable (https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) if you want to use immutable versions of `Map`, `Set`, etc. It's a large package, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question.

First I created an array of `selectedItems` in my global state.

Then I changed the `handleChecked` **onChange** method to add to the `selectedItems` array the checkboxes were checked.

And then any `selectedItems` that were `checked` and had a `productId` the style of the `checkbox container` would change.

Checkout the full code:

```js
class SelectArrayItemsWidget extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getReOrderBatteryAndAccessoriesInformationData();
  }

  handleChecked = e => {
    e.persist();
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedItems: prevState.selectedItems.concat(e.target.name),
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedItems: prevState.selectedItems.filter(i => i !== e.target.name),
      }));
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { supplies } = this.props;
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    return supplies.map(supply => (
      <div key={supply.productId} className="order-background">
        <p className="vads-u-font-size--md vads-u-font-weight--bold">
          {supply.productName}
        </p>
        <div className="vads-u-border-left--10px vads-u-border-color--primary-alt">
          <div className="usa-alert-body mdot-alert-body">
            <p className="vads-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="vads-u-font-weight--bold">Battery: </span>
              {supply.productId}
            </p>
            <p className="vads-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="vads-u-font-weight--bold">Quantity: </span>
              {supply.quantity} <br />
              Approximately {supply.quantity} months supply
            </p>
            <p className="vads-u-margin--1px">
              <span className="vads-u-font-weight--bold">
                Last order date:{' '}
              </span>{' '}
              {moment(supply.lastOrderDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            selectedItems.includes(supply.productId)
              ? 'vads-u-background-color--primary button-dimensions vads-u-color--white vads-u-border-color--primary vads-u-border--2px'
              : 'vads-u-background-color--white vads-u-color--link-default button-dimensions vads-u-border-color--primary vads-u-border--2px'
          }
        >
          <input
            name={supply.productId}
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={this.handleChecked}
          />
          <label htmlFor={supply.productId} className="main">
            Order batteries for this device
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}
```